# Respuesta de procedimiento almacenado (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy intentando hacer un procedimiento almacenado en SQL para un sistema de ventas de restaurante que al agregar un plato a una venta revise si hay stock disponible de los ingredientes y regrese una respuesta tipo **1** si hay o **0** si no hay.

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[check_stock_venta] 
@Idplato int,
@Cantidad int,
@Rpta int output
as
i.Stock;t.Cantidad from Insumos i join (select 
dp.id_insumo,Cantidad=sum(dp.Cantidad*@Cantidad) from Detalles_plato dp 
where dp.id_plato=@Idplato group by dp.id_insumo)t on i.Idinsumo=t.id_insumo
```

Por el momento he hecho un *join* de las tablas para tener los campos que necesito, había pensado en usar un *if* con los campos

- `i.Stock`
- `t.Cantidad`

y que este if devolviera la respuesta si el stock era mayor o igual que la cantidad, no se si sea la mejor forma de hacer esto y por otro lado no se como utilizar estos dos campos luego de hacer el join de las tablas.

Dejo un enlace donde se pueden ver [cómo están hechas y relacionadas las tablas](http://rextester.com/WRT88377).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si hay mas stock que la cantidad necesaria para el plato devuelve 1, si no devolverá 0, espero que te sirva.

```
Select CASE WHEN i.Stock >= t.Cantidad THEN 1 ELSE 0 END resultado 
from Insumos i join (select dp.id_insumo,Cantidad=sum(dp.Cantidad*@Cantidad) 
from Detalles_plato dp 
where dp.id_plato=@Idplato group by dp.id_insumo)t on i.Idinsumo=t.id_insumo
```

EDIT:

Nos quedamos con el minimo resultado de la lista de ingredientes, si retorna 1 todos los ingredientes tienen stock, sino alguno devolvio 0 y es falta stock de al menos un ingrediente.

```
select MIN(resultado) from (
Select CASE WHEN i.Stock >= t.Cantidad THEN 1 ELSE 0 END resultado 
from Insumos i join (select dp.id_insumo,Cantidad=sum(dp.Cantidad*@Cantidad) 
from Detalles_plato dp 
where dp.id_plato=@Idplato group by dp.id_insumo)t on i.Idinsumo=t.id_insumo
) as tt
```

Saludos,

Comment: Hola, hay algo que debí mencionar en mi post y se me paso y es que un plato puede tener mas de un ingrediente y estoy intentando que el procedimiento devuelva solo una respuesta y no una para cada ingrediente (si es que esto es posible)

Comment: Te actualice la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Este procedimiento regresa un valor escalar y revisa que todos los ingredientes tengan stock. No dará más detalles.

```
CREATE PROC dbo.check_stock_venta(
    @Idplato int, 
    @Cantidad int, 
    @Rpta int OUTPUT
)
AS
IF EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM Insumos AS i 
        WHERE EXISTS( SELECT 1
                    FROM Detalles_plato AS dp 
                    WHERE dp.id_plato = @Idplato 
                    AND i.Idinsumo = dp.id_insumo
                    GROUP BY dp.id_insumo
                    HAVING i.Stock >= sum(dp.Cantidad*@Cantidad))
        )
    SET @Rpta = 1;
ELSE
    SET @Rpta = 0;
```